# How strong should the air current from my heat pump be, and is there a way to adjust the power myself?

Tags: heat-pump

I've had a heatpump installed this spring. And it really feels like the air strength is not enough to circulate the hot hair around. So the temperature is unequal around the house, like floors being cold while the chest is fine.

My SO was the one that was there when they installed it, and of what I've heard, on normal power, the drapes were flying off, so they toned it down. I really wonder if the installer had it at 5/10, but since it was requested to tone it down he put it to the minimal 1/10.

So how strong should the air current be (if I put my hand on the air exit, for instance, or some other general test that shows its decent enough) and if it's too low, how can I adjust the power myself?

Comment: This is a central ducted unit? As opposed to mini-splits? Are you in a "primarily air-conditioning" climate? Pictures and model numbers, etc. would help in getting an answer you can use.

Comment: Room purpose and number of required air changes per hour is a starting point.

Comment: I'm really not expert. But its the kind of heatpump that is outside, goes to a furnace inside and then pushes the air through ducts throughout the house. does AC and Heating. I'm in Quebec, an environment where you have both.

Comment: They may have changed the blower motor speeds many do have multiple speeds but with the limited info provided guessing is a waste of time. What model of air handler and what blower motor?

Comment: search for the service manual for your furnace. There should be a series of DIP switches or jumpers that you can use to adjust the option.

Comment: Its a York. I don't really know how to check further the model in particular. But yeah I would still like to know how strong should the air current from my vents should be (just to know if its my imagination that its not strong enough)

Comment: You'll probably be money ahead having a pro in to adjust it, and ask them if there is or **is not** something you could adjust (and if so, how much) without hosing the system.

Comment: Yeah that was my fear. Pushing the heat pump to give more air could be like overclocking a computer. Yeah its fun, you get more performance, but take it too far and your motor will last half as long. Seeing the conversation here, I think I'll leave this whole thing in the hands of profesionnals.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standard ducted A/C unit you could check the temperature drop across the A/C coil using a thermometer. Check the air temperature entering the coil (return air) and the discharge air above the coil (cold supply air). The temperature drop should be between 15 & 20 degrees F. If the air temperature drop exceeds the 20 degrees F more air may be required. This is about all you can do yourself. The rest should be done by the installer or another HVAC company.

Comment: I think we're more interested in the temperature rise at this point in the year.

Comment: Then you need to consult the temperature rise spec sheet that used to be supplied with each unit or consult the mfg company.